# *ngFor: Parent element at array index resets Child component

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have a Parent Component with an array of Objects.

I use an *ngFor loop to populate Child Components via an @Input() with the element at each index.

If I change the object at an index, the child component completely resets instead of just accepting the new Input and maintaining it's other properties.

### [Stackblitz minimal example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v53dx6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

### TypeScript:

```
export interface MyObject {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

export class Parent {
  objectArray: MyObject[] = [
    {a: 'string A', b: 'string B'}
  ];

  changeAnObject() {
    const sameObject: MyObject = {a: 'string A', b: 'string B'};
    this.objectArray[0] = sameObject;
  }
}

export class Child {
  @Input() inputObject: MyObject;
  selected = false; // Some other property to maintain
}
```

### Parent HTML:

```
// 3 different ways to populate inputObject

<div *ngFor="let object of objectArray">
  <app-child [inputObject]="object"></app-child> // does not maintain "selected" property
</div>

<div *ngFor="let object of objectArray; let index = index">
  <app-child [inputObject]="objectArray[index]"></app-child> // does not maintain "selected" property
</div>

<div>
  <app-child [inputObject]="objectArray[0]"></app-child> // DOES maintain "selected" property
</div>

<button (click)="changeAnObject()">Change Object</button>
```

### Child HTML:

```
<div (click)="selected = !selected">
    a: {{inputObject.a}}
    b: {{inputObject.b}}
    SELECTED: {{selected}}
</div>
```

### Result

In the parent HTML, `[inputObject]="objectArray[0]"` is the only solution I've found which maintains the other properties of Child when changing the element in `objectArray[0]`.

This is not good enough for me as I have many objects to display.

Is there a better way to send data into Components without resetting them entirely?
I have attempted using `Angular Accessors` with `@Input() set inputObject {...}` but it has not worked to maintain the Component's properties. That is, the constructor executes again when `inputObject` changes, resetting all properties to default values.

Comment: Same behavior if you use `push()` instead of inserting directly the object by index ? `this.objectArray.push(sameObject);`

Comment: @XavierBrassoud, That doesn't have quite the same effect as adding a new object would require a new, additional <child> to be created anyway. That would certainly create a new <child> and set it to default properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to track by your object by some index, that will not change after you execute your changeAnObject action.

```
<div *ngFor="let object of objectArray; let index = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

with your trackByFn being:

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
   return item.a; 
}
```

Just do it like this and it will work! :)

What it does is that by tracking the object by an unique and non changing id, it will not reiterate through the ngFor loop because it detected that the id that is tracking the loop has not been changed

My example was based on your stackBlitz